# Find intersection of 2 large sorted arrays using MapReduce

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce

How do you find the intersection of 2 large sorted arrays using MapReduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think MapReduce is the right tool; since your arrays are sorted, you could do what amounts to a merge except that instead of gathering up all of the results, you only keep those that appear in both arrays.  Nice linear algorithm.  But since you asked...

The Map part of MapReduce takes in a set of (key,value) pairs.  So give one where each pair corresponds to a element in one of the arrays, with key being the element's value and the value identifying which array it came from.  Then reduce throws out any key which doesn't have a value from both arrays.  I'll leave dealing with duplicates as an exercise.